# How do I convert 'Buffer.from' from NodeJS to browser version

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

The previous posts pertaining to this issue are more than 7 years old, so I am hoping that the current version of javascript has a new solution.

I am converting a `node.js` script to a version that will run in the browser, and the following lines of code are throwing errors:

```
Buffer.from('1901', 'hex')
Buffer.from('Hello World')
```

Please indicate how I can modify those commands so they will run in the browser.

Please do not refer to 3rd party libraries in your solution. If Browserify is the solution, then please provide the exact `**script src=**` to add.

Comment: It's  not available in native js as V8 browser  engine won't support it.

Comment: Is there any code that provides the same functionality in native js?

Comment: You said no 3rd party libs.

Comment: If it's a widely used 3rd party lib (like Browserify), and if it's as simple as adding a **script src=** tag, then I would like to know about it.